# Angular, Display Collection as comma separated values

Tags: html, angularjs

How to display the collection returned by get as comma separated values?

```
<div ng-repeat="val in cc.getRepeatingAttributeValues(col.name)">
    <span class="value">{{val}}</span>                                                  
</div>
```

`getRepeatingAttributesValues()` returns `["Consumers","Contributors"]` I want it to be displayed as

`Consumer,Contributors`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with **[Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)** :

```
{{ cc.getRepeatingAttributeValues(col.name).join() }}
```